# React Native - GoogleSignIn - refreshToken, idToken, accessTokenExpirationDate are all null

Tags: react-native, oauth, openid, google-signin, refresh-token

I am trying to use expo-google-sign-in in my project. I am able to login with GoogleSignIn.signInAsync() but in the object I get back as a result the refreshToken, idToken and accessTokenExpirationDate are all null. Does anybody have any idea what the problem can be? I use **expo 4.2.1**. I have ejected the project and run it with **react-native run-android**

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as GoogleSignIn from 'expo-google-sign-in';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button title='sign in' onPress={async () => {
        await GoogleSignIn.initAsync({
          clientId: '<MY CLIENT ID>',
          scopes: [
            GoogleSignIn.SCOPES.OPEN_ID
          ],
        });
        const r = await GoogleSignIn.signInAsync();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
      }}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And the result is something like this:

```
{
"type": "success",
"user": {
    "uid": "8978924659847365874563486867",
    "email": "john.bar@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "John Bar",
    "photoURL": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AjsgdyegdrR-_wluyiuBUUKDKWBUWYDKUWGHDjO-M",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Bar",
    "auth": {
        "idToken": null,
        "refreshToken": null,
        "accessToken": "ya29.a0AfH6SMCh1K322dfdf34rff6_gGHW98-kIngxBUUTtfRZTugtwff4f4wf4f4wf4fPib9fc2JPXmg7ewfGx7peVtC4ffwfw4fwfw4fw4fBeFkqJydbWxcwiUb",
        "accessTokenExpirationDate": null
    },
    "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
    ],
    "serverAuthCode": null
}
```

}

What is also strange that the scopes field in the result doesn't contain openid.

These are my credentials in my google cloud console (the SHA1 fingerprint comes from debug.keystore).

[image]

The Consent setup

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am running in to the same problem but not sure what to do...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `webClientId` instead of `clientId` in initAsync It worked for me.

```
 await GoogleSignIn.initAsync({
        webClientId: '<MY CLIENT ID>',
    });
```